# Pandas group by window range

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following data table:

```
values
======
2.0
2.5
3.2 
7.0
7.8
9.0
11.0
```

I want to extract groups witzhin a certain window, for example

```
window_size = 1.0
```

All values within this distance should become one group:

```
values   group
======   ====
2.0      1
2.5      1
3.2      1
7.0      2
7.8      2
9.0      3
11.0     4
```

3.2 and 2.0 are in one group because 2.5 is between them and to both sides below the windows size 1.0.

How to achieve this with pandas?

**Edit1** (more sophisticated example return wrong group with the answers below):

```
windows_size= 1000000
value          group    correct_group
65951649.0     1        1  
59397882.0     1        2
7633231.0      1        3 
7638485.0      1        3
68085447.0     2        4
67973423.0     2        4
```

**Edit2** Follow up question, is it possible to group by another group:
[Pandas group by window range (Follow up question with category)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68529463/pandas-group-by-window-range-follow-up-question-with-category)

Comment: what's the window size in the last example?

Comment: sorry I forgot, 1000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC use `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
window_size = 1.0
df["group"] = df["values"].diff().abs().gt(window_size).cumsum()+1
print (df)

   values  group
0     2.0      1
1     2.5      1
2     3.2      1
3     7.0      2
4     7.8      2
5     9.0      3
6    11.0      4
```

Comment: Thanks I tried but with another example the grouping seems to be not correct.

Comment: @honeymoon - Use `df["group"] = df["value"].diff().abs().gt(windows_size).cumsum()+1`

Comment: Is it possible to combine it with  second group (see my second edit)?

Comment: @honeymoon - Is possible post new question for it?

Comment: Please stop updating your question over and over with new data. Also the answer above is in line with your new data. Ask a new question instead if you found extreme cases that you need to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You can create groups using pandas diff

```
df['group'] = (df['values'].diff().abs().fillna(100) > window_size).astype(int).cumsum()
```

Here, the fill value should be a number greater than window_size

Output:

```
   values  group
0     2.0      1
1     2.5      1
2     3.2      1
3     7.0      2
4     7.8      2
5     9.0      3
6    11.0      4
```

Comment: Thanks I tried but with another example the grouping seems to be not correct.