# Pandas group by window range (Follow up question with category)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

[Follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68527072/pandas-group-by-window-range/68527189?noredirect=1#comment121110381_68527189):

I have the following data table:
I want to extract groups within a certain window and category, for example windows_size= 1000000

```
value          category    
65951649.0     A         
59397882.0     A       
7633231.0      A        
7638485.0      A       
65951649.0     B         
59397882.0     B       
7633231.0      B        
7638485.0      B   

Output:
value          category    group
65951649.0     A        1  
59397882.0     A        2
7633231.0      A        3 
7638485.0      A        3
65951649.0     B        1  
59397882.0     B        2
7633231.0      B        3 
7638485.0      B        3
```

Is it possible to do it inside the data frame or I have to do it for each category in a separate data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom lambda function:

```
window_size = 1000000
f = lambda x: x.diff().abs().gt(window_size).cumsum()
df["group"] = df.groupby('category')["value"].apply(f)+1
print (df)
        value category  group
0  65951649.0        A      1
1  59397882.0        A      2
2   7633231.0        A      3
3   7638485.0        A      3
4  65951649.0        B      1
5  59397882.0        B      2
6   7633231.0        B      3
7   7638485.0        B      3
```

Or double `groupby`, because need difference and cumulative sum per groups:

```
df["group"] = (df.groupby('category')["value"].diff().abs().gt(window_size)
                 .groupby(df['category']).cumsum()+1)
```

Comment: I have problem with this specific file but I can not figure out whats the reason. If I try the category separately  it works but not if they are in one dataset. https://rentry.co/msdfa

Comment: @honeymoon try change `df.groupby('category')` to `df.groupby('category', sort=False)`

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem there was a duplicate of one value in category 7.